# AuthorizedHandler Blocked wrong request! url: /socket.io/

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm using mrniko/netty-socketio (Java) to start a websocket server like this:

```
config = new Configuration();
config.setHostname("localhost");
config.setPort(8001);
server = new SocketIOServer(config);
server.addListeners(serviceClass);
server.start();
```

Then I'm using (the recommended) socketio/socket.io-client (JavaScript) to try to connect to the websocket server like this (all on the same server):

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:8001");
```

The connection is "blocked" at the server with the server printing:

```
8239 [nioEventLoopGroup-5-1] WARN com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.AuthorizeHandler  - Blocked wrong request! url: /socket.io/, ip: /127.0.0.1:48915
28889 [nioEventLoopGroup-5-2] WARN com.corundumstudio.socketio.handler.AuthorizeHandler  - Blocked wrong request! url: /socket.io/, ip: /127.0.0.1:48916
```

Which occurs endlessly, as the client continues to retry the connection.

I can't seem to get the server to accept the connection. I've tried:

```
var socket = io("ws://localhost:8001");
```

But that gives the same outcome. I've also tried putting a trailing slash after the URL for both cases - makes no difference. I've also tried all combinations of using "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" at both the server and client, and so on.

The JavaScript page itself is being served up from a http server on `localhost:8000`. This does not appear to be a cross site issue as that gives an entirely different error at the browser.

Does anyone know what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case network monitoring accesses that port every 10 seconds. I had temporarily changed log4j.properties to ERROR level logging, but wanted to provide networking a path to use that would not cause excessive warn logging. Not sure if this was the best approach, but this is what I ended up doing.

config.setAllowCustomRequests(true); 
By allowing custom requests the piece of code displaying the warning was bypassed in Authorizehandler.

I created a custom pipeline, that allowed me to switch out the wrongUrlHandler with a custom one to allow a safe path to use for monitoring.

```
public class CustomSocketIOChannelInitializer extends SocketIOChannelInitializer {

   CustomWrongUrlHandler customWrongUrlHandler = null;

   public CustomSocketIOChannelInitializer(Configuration configuration) {
      customWrongUrlHandler = new CustomWrongUrlHandler(configuration);
   }

   protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
       ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
       addSslHandler(pipeline);
       addSocketioHandlers(pipeline);
       // Replace wrong url handler with our custom one to allow network monitoring without logging warnings.
       pipeline.replace(SocketIOChannelInitializer.WRONG_URL_HANDLER, "CUSTOM_WRONG_URL_HANDLER", customWrongUrlHandler);
   }
```

This is my custom handler:

```
@Sharable
public class CustomWrongUrlHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    Configuration configuration = null;

    /**
    * @param configuration
    */
   public CustomWrongUrlHandler(Configuration configuration) {
       this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {

       if (msg instanceof FullHttpRequest) {
          FullHttpRequest req = (FullHttpRequest) msg;
          Channel channel = ctx.channel();
          QueryStringDecoder queryDecoder = new QueryStringDecoder(req.getUri());

          // Don't log when port is pinged for monitoring. Must use context that starts with /ping.
          if (configuration.isAllowCustomRequests() && queryDecoder.path().startsWith("/ping")) {
              HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
              channel.writeAndFlush(res).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
              req.release();
              //log.info("Blocked wrong request! url: {}, ip: {}", queryDecoder.path(), channel.remoteAddress());
              return;
          } 

          // This is the last channel handler in the pipe so if it is not ping then log warning.
          HttpResponse res = new DefaultHttpResponse(HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
          ChannelFuture f = channel.writeAndFlush(res);
          f.addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);
          req.release();
          log.warn("Blocked wrong socket.io-context request! url: {}, params: {}, ip: {}", channel.remoteAddress() + " " + queryDecoder.path(), queryDecoder.parameters());
      }
    }
}


 CustomSocketIOChannelInitializer customSocketIOChannelInitializer = new CustomSocketIOChannelInitializer(config);
  server.setPipelineFactory(customSocketIOChannelInitializer);
```